# langchain - Azure OpenAI api - returning additional information than the asked question

Tags: azure, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to develop a chatbot using streamlit,langchain Azure OpenAI api.
I have been successful in deploying the model and invoking an response but it is not what I expect.
here is the prompt and the code that to invoke the API

```
llm = AzureOpenAI(model_name="gpt-35-turbo",
                  temperature=0,
                  openai_api_key=open_api_key,
                  openai_api_base=openai_api_base,
                  openai_api_type=openai_api_type,
                  openai_api_version=openai_api_version,
                  deployment_name=openai_deployment) 

embedding = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=open_api_key,
                             deployment=open_ai_embed_model,
                             openai_api_base=openai_api_base,
                             openai_api_type=openai_api_type,
                             )
prompt_template = """Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.
Just answer the question asked. do not provide additional question and helpful answers
{context}

Question: {question}
"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question"]
)
```

Code to invoke the chain and pass the prompt

```
chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
qa_chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
       llm,
       retriever=retriever,
       chain_type="stuff",
       chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs
)
result = qa_chain.run(user_input)
```

now if I ask it a question such as

> What is the limit of breakfast

I get the correct response such as

> A: 20$

But the issue is after that I get bunch of additional information in a question answer format which although is produced using the context but not requested such as

> Question: What is the limit for Laundary? Answer: 10$ Question:
> Question: What is the guideline for selecting flights for domestic
> flights? Answer: Helpful answer

It seems like model is trying to use maximum tokens allowed despite clear instruction in prompt to not provide any additional information.
How can I control this any inputs will be helpful?

**P.S: it work properly if I use OpenAI model rather than Azure OpenAI model**

Comment: Please edit your question and include how you’re creating an instance of LLM.

Comment: added the llm instance details

Comment: Please try by replacing `AzureOpenAI` with `AzureChatOpenAI`. I ran into this similar problem and making this change solved my problem. I had to make some other changes though (like I ended up removing using chain etc.). You can see my code here: https://github.com/gmantri/azure-docs-copilot/blob/main/src/index.py.

Comment: Thanks a lot, just changing to AzureChatOpenAI solve the problem and I didn't event had to ditch the chain. You are a lifesaver. thanks again

Comment: Awesome! Let me post this as an answer shortly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try by replacing “AzureOpenAI” with “AzureChatOpenAI”. I ran into this similar problem and making this change solved my problem.